# How to allow loading png from http via adding NSExceptionDomains in ATS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, nsapptransportsecurity

in exercise https://github.com/Mairoslav/5networkAndGDC/tree/main/ImageRequest I would like to allow the jpg to be loaded from the web site with "http" scheme by adjusting NSAppTransportSecurity in Info.plist as written below. I do not want to allow any other "http" sites, therefore opted to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to false. If you can advice.

```
<dict>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.kittenswhiskers.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Even after these adjustments, there is an error: "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection." I have tried all alternative options for NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion. The sources I was using were: https://agilie.com/blog/how-to-add-domain-exceptions-to-comply-with-apples-new-ats-requirements, https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-app-transport-security-exception-domains and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my test code and `Info.plist`, that works well for me. Tested on real devices, not Previews.

The Info.plist

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <dict>

     <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
     <dict>
         <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
         <false/>
         <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
         <dict>
             <key>www.kittenswhiskers.com</key>
             <dict>
                 <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                 <true/>
                 <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                 <true/>
                 <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                 <string>TLSv1.0</string>
                 <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                 <false/>
             </dict>
         </dict>
     </dict>

 </dict>
 </plist>
```

The test code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var image = UIImage()
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: image)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(width: 333, height: 333)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .task {
                if let url = URL(string: "http://www.kittenswhiskers.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/23/2014/02/Kitten-playing-with-yarn.jpg") {
                    image = await loadImage(url: url)
                }
            }
    }
    
    func loadImage(url: URL) async -> UIImage {
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let img = UIImage(data: data) { return img }
        }
        catch { print(error) }
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @workingdog support Ukraine, thank you for your support, in Info.plist I left only the code related to NSAppTransportSecurity, the rest I deleted. Also I did run it on real device. I tried to adjust the code as per your test code, however did not succeed - do not yet understand all syntax used. Only could put together the version based on lesson. Just would like to ask whether this version https://github.com/Mairoslav/5networkAndGDC/tree/main/ImageRequest does work at your side. Possibly what shall be adjusted.

Comment: I did have the Info.plist in the Xcode two times so it did not work because of this. Now having one Info.plist with the settings as you posted it works. Thanks, nice day.